# Integrating $\sin(\tan^{-1}(x))\ dx$

Tags: calculus

Title says it all. I'm trying to find

$$\int\sin(\tan^{-1}(x))\ dx$$

I checked on WolframAlpha which says the answer is $\sqrt{x^2+1}+C$ but I really don't know where to start for this integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  Draw yourself a right triangle.  The argument for $tan^{-1}$ is a ratio of two sides relative to an angle.  Say one of them is x, and the other 1.  Then you are taking the $sin$ of that angle, which is a ratio of sides (you can get the hypotenuse using Pythagorean theorem).  From this, you should get your integrand to be $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$.

From there, you can integrate using trig substitution.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\sin(\tan^{-1}(x))=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\displaystyle\arctan x=u\implies x=\tan u$

and $\displaystyle-\dfrac\pi2\le u\le\dfrac\pi2\implies\sec u=+\sqrt{1+\tan^2u}$

$$\int\sin(\arctan x)dx=\int\sin u\sec^2u \ du=\int\sec u\tan u du=\sec u+C$$

Comment: how did $\sin u\sec^2u$ become $\tan u$?

Comment: @user137794, sorry for the mistake